# How to create indexes to speed up my join query in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have two tables, one is the master table, `phonebook`, and the other is the detail table, `entries`.
Each row in `entries` references to a unique contact in `phonebook`. A contact may have multiple labeled rows in `entries`, for example.

```
id: 1, label: 'family telno', value='+1982'
id: 1, label: 'official email', value='aaa@hotmail.com'
```

For you convience, I post the sql statements to construct the database:

```sql
create table phonebook (id int primary key, name text not null);
create table entries (id int not null references phonebook(id),
  label text not null, value text not null);
create unique index idx_entries_labelvalue on entries(label, value);

insert into phonebook (id, name) values(1, 'amy'),(2, 'bob');
insert into entries (id, label, value) values
  (1,'famtelno', '1234'), (1,'offemail', 'amy@a.com'),
  (2,'offtelno', '9876'),(2,'offemail', 'bob@b.com');
```

I often need to find all rows for a contact with the same `id` based on specified labled value in `entries`.

Just like:

```sql
select t2.id, t2.name, t2.label, t2.value 
from entries t1 
inner join (
  select t3.id, t3.name, t4.label, t4.value 
  from phonebook t3 
  inner join entries t4 on t3.id=t4.id
) t2 on t1.id=t2.id 
where t1.label='offemail' 
  and t1.value='amy@a.com';

 id | name |  label   |   value   
----+------+----------+-----------
  1 | amy  | famtelno | 1234      
  1 | amy  | offemail | amy@a.com 

(2 rows)
```

So I check the plan of the query:

```
$ explain select t2.id, t2.name, t2.label, t2.value from entries t1 inner join (select t3.id, t3.name, t4.label, t4.value from phonebook t3 inner join entries t4 on t3.id=t4.id) t2 on t1.id=t2.id where t1.label='offemail' and t1.value='amy@a.com';
                                                QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=8.33..29.86 rows=1 width=100)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=8.18..28.96 rows=4 width=72)
         Hash Cond: (t4.id = t1.id)
         ->  Seq Scan on entries t4  (cost=0.00..18.50 rows=850 width=68)
         ->  Hash  (cost=8.17..8.17 rows=1 width=4)
               ->  Index Scan using idx_entries_labelvalue on entries t1  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=4)
                     Index Cond: ((label = 'offemail'::text) AND (value = 'amy@a.com'::text))
   ->  Index Scan using phonebook_pkey on phonebook t3  (cost=0.15..0.23 rows=1 width=36)
         Index Cond: (id = t4.id)
(9 rows)
```

It seems not very good. So I create index on entries.id.

```
$ create index idx_entries_id on entries(id);
CREATE INDEX
$ explain select t2.id, t2.name, t2.label, t2.value from entries t1 inner join (select t3.id, t3.name, t4.label, t4.value from phonebook t3 inner join entries t4 on t3.id=t4.id) t2 on t1.id=t2.id where t1.label='offemail' and t1.value='amy@a.com';
                                        QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.15..8.33 rows=1 width=100)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..2.15 rows=1 width=72)
         Join Filter: (t1.id = t4.id)
         ->  Seq Scan on entries t1  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=1 width=4)
               Filter: ((label = 'offemail'::text) AND (value = 'amy@a.com'::text))
         ->  Seq Scan on entries t4  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=4 width=68)
   ->  Index Scan using phonebook_pkey on phonebook t3  (cost=0.15..6.17 rows=1 width=36)
         Index Cond: (id = t4.id)
(8 rows)
```

Some `seq scan` still can be found in query. Why?

How can I improve the query?

Comment: Could you please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your SQL statement? In plain text, as an update to your question.

Comment: By the way, with a handful of records it's a waste of time to execute an index scan: A sequential read is most likely faster. Always test with a large number of records, something that you will have in production

Comment: You should solve real problems, not imagined ones.  With very small tables any plan is likely to be good enough.  If you have a real problem, show an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for it, preferably with track_io_timing turned on.

Comment: @FrankHeikens thank you very much. I might have been overly concerned about seq scan. Currently, it seems that these queries are performing well, and I just envisioned a potential issue in the future with a large number of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very difficult to provide index suggestions -- safe for the most simple cases -- without having a profound understanding on the data distribution and selectivities. My best guess is shown below:

First, I would rephrase the query in a simpler way, so the optimizer can have more chances of finding good paths:

```sql
select t3.id, t3.name, t4.label, t4.value 
from entries t1 
join phonebook t3 on t1.id = t3.id 
join entries t4 on t3.id = t4.id
where t1.label = 'offemail' 
  and t1.value = 'amy@a.com';
```

In this case, I would create the following indexes:

```sql
create index ix1 on entries (value, label); -- to access t1

create index ix2 on phonebook (id) include (name); -- to access t3

create index ix3 on entries (id) include (label, value); -- to access t4
```